# Find all non-conventional single quote marks

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to get all of the records from a column (Last Name) that have a non-conventional apostrophe character.

i.e, `U+2019`, `U+2018`, `U+201B` (anything else?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expresion class to filter the rows like this:

```
select * from table where regexp_like(last_name, '[‘’`´‘’‛′‵]')
```

or if you don't want to use unicode characters directly in your string:

```
select * from table where regexp_like(last_name, '[' || unistr('\2018\2019\201B`\00B4\2032\2035') || ']')
```

There are even more non conventional single quote marks to be found in unicode: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Punctuation

Pay attention to some of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks as they could be combined with spaces to make it look like quotes.